# How to align panels with BoxLayout and FlowLayout

Tags: java, layout-manager

Here is the code:

```
//Top-level container
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

//JPanel 1
JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
BoxLayout b1 = new BoxLayout(p1, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
p1.setLayout(b1);
p1.add(new JButton("1"));
p1.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
p1.add(new JButton("1"));

//JPanel 2
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
FlowLayout fl = new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING, 0, 0);
p2.setLayout(fl);
p2.add(new JButton("2"));
p2.add(new JButton("2"));
p2.add(new JButton("2"));
p2.add(new JButton("2"));
p2.add(new JButton("2"));


panel.add(p1);
panel.add(p2);
```

This code produces the following window:

[image]

But this is not exactly what I wanted. The rightmost button's border is not aligned. Is there a way to put these components this way:

[image]

Comment: For this kind of layout I'd use GridBag or a layout editor like [Matisse.](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html)  I don't think you can do it with the layouts you currently have.

Comment: `FlowLayout` is not good at that. Try to put a `GridLayout(1,<number of buttons>)` to `b2` .

Comment: @markspace Well, the problem seems very typical and quite simple...

Comment: It is typical.  That's why there's Grid/GridBag layout.

Comment: @markspace But why does the flowlayout put this gap on the right, but BoxLayout doesnt? Maybe there is a way to just remove it

Comment: Because they're different.

Comment: By the way, JPanel has FlowLayout as default layout